# Всемирное наследие

Tags: прописная-строчная

С прописной или строчной пишется первое слово в сочетании "всемирное наследие ЮНЕСКО"?

Answer (score 1):

В справочнике по русскому языку ***Д.Э. Розенталь "Прописная или строчная?"*** есть выражение Всемирное наследие. Написано именно так. Думаю, что правильно будет ***Всемирное наследие ЮНЕСКО.***

Comment: В справочнике Розенталя "Прописная или строчная?" (1984) этого сочетания нет. У Лопатина в аналогичном справочнике тоже нет. Грамота говорит, что корректно "Список Всемирного наследия ЮНЕСКО", но без ссылки на источник. Кстати, в печати, используют "Список Всемирного наследия ЮНЕСКО", но "реестр Всемирного наследия ЮНЕСКО". В словарях на Яндексе чаще встречается сочетание с реестром. Где люди берут подтверждение выбранного написания? ))

Comment: Справочник Розенталя передо мной. М., "Мир и Образование", 2003. Стр.30. Всемирное наследие. Всемирное - с прописной.

Comment: Да, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

"Всемирное" пишется с прописной буквы, а "наследие" — со строчной.

Comment: Если можно, источник укажите, пожалуйста. Не Грамоту )

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, ЧТО имеется в виду под "всемирным наследием"? Если так называется журнал, альманах (кажется, нечто подобное существует), то в названии этого издания первое слово - с прописной буквы. В противном случае у Вас все написано верно

Comment: Думаю, у меня все же написано неверно )